# What is the difference between OBD1 and OBD2?

Tags: obd-ii, bmw, obd, obd-i, 323i

In my car (BMW E46 323I 1998) I have both connectors, that is, the 20-pin OBD1 and the OBD2, what is the difference between the two, I am referring rather to the functionality in my car, that is .

**OBD1:**
[image]

**OBD2:**
[image]

With one I can somehow access the switchboard in a "deeper" way to the switchboard? Or certain information will only be given to me from one of the two? Also say that I have the 20-pin OBD1 on the hood, while I have the 16-pin inside the car, under the steering wheel.

Comment: Here in the States almost every car 1996 and newer utilizes only the OBDII connector. I know vehicles sold in Europe didn't necessarily go completely over to OBDII until a little later (I don't remember off the top of my head when). Some cars had it; others didn't. I can suppose some had both? OBDII will give you a huge amount more data than would OBDI. If OBDII is available, use it ... you can't go wrong. I don't think this answers your question, so leaving it as a comment.

Comment: I would suggest to ask this question on a BMW owners group forum or facebook group, surely they can answer it for you

Comment: With OBD-2 you can read only engine errors, as I know, but if you connect under the hood, you can read all car and program it with INPA